# WebRequest returning more source than Browser > view source

Tags: c#, html, .net, http, selenium

I am writing a Selenium utility in C# to help with automated testing. I may be missing something completely obvious here, but why is it that if I send an HttpWebRequest off to a server and retrieve the response stream, I end up with more source (i.e more mappable WebElements for Selenium) than I get when I right-click - view page source in my browser?

This means that I am mapping elements that the Selenium driver cant find come runtime.

Me so confuse :S

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());

var src = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code to reproduce, and some sample input/output? I can think of a few possible reasons for the behavior you're describing, but more detail would be useful.

Comment: Basically, I am sending an HttpWebRequest off to "http://www.google.com", and reading the source code from the response stream. However, I am getting back content, for example; href links, that I cant find when I search the source code in FireFox. Sample code is pretty standard and probably not useful (just a web request to Google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of possibilities. One likely culprit is the difference in the information you're sending to the server. Browsers typically send various headers, cookies, etc., that a web request does not have unless you explicitly add it.

For example, when I hit www.google.com with my web browser, I get stuff from Google Plus, and I get the fanciest experience possible because I'm on an evergreen browser. Roughly 139000 characters appear in my View Source page.

However, when I do a web request to the same URL (using the following code), I get only 45000 characters in the response stream:

```
async void Main()
{
    var result = await GetTextAsync("https://www.google.com");
    Console.Write(result.Length);
}

public async Task<string> GetTextAsync(string url){
    var result = await WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponseAsync();
    using (var stream = result.GetResponseStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

I suspect that if I were to set the WebRequest to send all the same cookies and headers that Chrome is sending to Google, my results would be much more similar.

Comment: But that's what is confusing me... I am getting more back from my 'header-less' code request that I am from my browser. Would I expect to see more content rendered in my browser? or could it work both ways in that a naked request could in-fact return more that that of one sent from a browser.

Comment: @DawnFreeze: Perhaps. I *would* expect it to have elements that don't exist in the browser's version. Without the headers, Google has to assume that you're using the most basic browser possible (think: a blackberry or something), so it's rendering the page in plain HTML. With the headers, it knows that it can rely heavily on javascript, so most of the content is in one big `<script>` tag. The actual DOM content you see in the browser gets generated from that javascript.

Comment: I see, will investigate... Thank you for your help :)